# how to return an array from a procedure in TCL?

Tags: arrays, tcl

I am calling TCL code from Java and would like to get an array back. I've read that in TCL this isn't possible and you have to use other approaches. I feel like I've tried every possible combination with upvar and dict and what not, but I cannot get it to work. How do I get my array from the procedure?

```
 proc getOld {} {
   set tempList {}
   set myArray [setK $tempList]
   puts [array size $myArray]
}

getOld
```

Thanks for any help and tips!

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's arrays are collections of variables (e.g., the individual elements can be traced) and as such are not first class values, and cannot be passed directly. Instead, they are either passed by name or a serialised version of the array is passed.

With **pass by name**, the caller gives the name of a variable and the called procedure uses `upvar` to bind that name to a local variable that it can update; the updates are visible outside the procedure.

However, when you're integrating with Java it is better to use a **serialised value** approach. The procedure just uses `array get` to convert an array to a *dictionary* value which can be returned. Dictionaries are very much like Java's `HashMap` class.

```
proc foo {} {
    # Do stuff here to make the array...

    return [array get theArray]
}
```

You can also use the `dict` command to create and work with dictionaries directly. On the Java side, dictionaries should be accessed via the [`TclDict`](https://jtcl-project.github.io/jtcl/apidocs/tcl/lang/TclDict.html) class. (I assume you're using JTcl; if not, you're making life a bit awkward for yourself…)